# Python logger override filename

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am following object oriented design for the python package and here is how I have created logger and used in classes -

**logger.py**

```
from logging import getLogger, config
class MyLogger():
  
  def __init__(self, config_path):
    config.fileConfig(config_path)
    self.logger = getLogger()
  
  def debug(self, message):
    self.logger.debug(message)
```

**client.py**

```
from logger import Logger
class Client():
  
  def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
    self.logger = logger
```

**service.py**

```
from logger import Logger
class Service():
  
  def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
    self.logger = logger
```

**log_config.conf**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=console

[formatters]
keys=std_out

[logger_root]
handlers=console
level=DEBUG

[handler_console]
class=logging.StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=std_out

[formatter_std_out]
format=%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(filename)s: %(message)s
```

Issue is if I call the `debug()` method of `MyLogger` from `client.py` or `service.py` it prints the message but the `filename` it always shows as `logger.py`. Is there a way to override the `filename` content? Or does the design needs to be changed?

Comment: using the loggeradapter for preserving the original logger's functionality
but allowing it to show the correct caller's information when it logs a message.

Comment: @HasanRaza any example?

Comment: YUP I CAN PROVIDE YOU THE EXAMPLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**logger.py**

```
from logging import getLogger, config, LoggerAdapter

class MyLogger():
  
  def __init__(self, config_path):
    config.fileConfig(config_path)
    self.logger = getLogger()
  
  def debug(self, message):
    self.logger.debug(message)

  def get_logger_adapter(self):
    return LoggerAdapter(self.logger, {})
```

**client.py**

```
from logger import MyLogger
class Client():
  
  def __init__(self, logger: MyLogger):
    self.logger = logger.get_logger_adapter()
```

**service.py**

```
from logger import MyLogger
class Service():  
  def __init__(self, logger: MyLogger):
    self.logger = logger.get_logger_adapter()
```

when you use logger in Client or Service class filename and linenumber will reflect the correct location from where debug() method is called

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed for logger.error() it doesn't show the complete stacktrace. Like if I call `Client -> call()` from inside `Service -> call()` then I noticed I do not get the complete stacktrace if `Client -> call()` raises an exception.